# pkill wild card in user name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, pkill

I have a gitlab process running under the username `gitlab-+`. I would like to kill all processes from the user.

When I try:

```
pkill -9 -u gitlab-+
```

It comes back with invalid user name. I tried

```
pkill -9 -u gitlab* with the same result. How can I specify a wildcard in the `-u` argument for `pkill`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use wild-char in in the effective user ID flag for pkill  ... looks like only a coma separated list of UID or usrnames.
You might be able to work around the issue with something like this:

```
pkill -9 -u $(awk -F: '/^gitlab.*/ {printf("%s,",$1)}' < /etc/passwd)
```

Comment: I see the last "," with nothing behind it makes a mess ... you'll haveto remove it else you will kill unwanted stuff
pkill -9 -u $(awk -F: '/^gitlab.*/ {printf("%s,",$1)}' < /etc/passwd)  |sed 's/, *$//')
might do it right

Answer (score 0):

You can use user ID to kill the process.
Get the user id i.e. a unique integer number of user by running:

```
id <username>
```

And then kill all the processes by using the same command, use userid i.e. the integer number instead of username.

Hope this helps.